# Controlling image position in jquery slider via CSS only?

Tags: jquery, css

Seems every day I have a CSS question lately. I hope soon I will be returning the favor. So now I am trying to modify a jquery slider to shift the position of an image and description overlay. The site I am working on is [here](http://dev.pfp-consortium.org)

Note the slider, which contains a navigation section on left, an image, and a description overlaid on the bottom right of the image. Right now there is a lot of blank space between the slider block and the newsletter block to its right. What I want to do is have the navigation part stay where it is, and for the image and the description to move together to the right by a specified amount. Ideally I am trying to do this in CSS alone.

Here is part of the CSS, which is what I think I should be interested in:

```
jo-k2-main-outer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If I add left: 120px; then I see in Firebug that the div containing the image now occupies the space I want, but the position of the image itself (with description overlaid) is not changing and is being cut off on the right by an amount equal to the 120px. So I figure maybe I need to edit the jquery. For instance, in firebug I see JoK2Slide(document).ready( function($){ which has a marginleft param set to 5px but editing that (e.g. to 125px) does not produce a result. And besides, I am really trying to accomplish this in CSS only.

Any ideas on how to go about this as simply as possible?

Thanks as always, regards

Comment: I think the best way is, you make the images wider. Otherwise the images need to be scaled.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I needed to set the corresponding element width (which is set inline in the module code) to 100%! Now all is well.

```
<div id="jo-k2-slide45" class="jo-k2-slidecontent  jo-k2-snleft topslider" style="height: 275px; width: 100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with the css, you just need to made some change below than you are good to go.

Change the following css in your style.css

```
.jo-k2-main-outer{
  left :0;
}
```

--> by doing this you will see the image shifts to the right.
    You can also see a dot is appearing near the image, to remove this you need to do change the following css

```
ul.jo-k2-main-wapper li{
 list-style: outside none none;
}
```

let me know if you have any other issuse.

Thanks.